# Android SDK Facebook login button error

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to install a Facebook login button to my android application. I'm using AndroidSDK and getting following error:

```
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.frederik.testpleasework, PID: 2218
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.frederik.testpleasework/com.example.frederik.testpleasework.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.frederik.testpleasework.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.frederik.testpleasework.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.frederik.testpleasework.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:136)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.<init>(AccessTokenTracker.java:55)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2.<init>(LoginButton.java:561)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:561)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:66)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:200)
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.frederik.testpleasework.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-14 16:08:24.733 2218-2218/com.example.frederik.testpleasework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I already set it up using their form:
[image]

(Inserted all the other information as well, but I believe this is what's relevant)

Having an idea the error might lie in my manifest, I'll provide that aswell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.frederik.testpleasework" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After scavenging the internet for solutions my own idea of the error might be a wrongful setup on the FB page or bad code in the manifest. However I have not managed to locate it, and hope you guys can help.

Thank you in advance =)

Comment: The reason is in your stack trace: `Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.`

Comment: After trying to enter the code I get an error: Can not resolve method "sdkInitialize()". Maybe I'm placing it wrong? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following will help you.
1) Place your code of Facebook initialize very after the super.on create. before setcontent view.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

2) secondly you didnt define facebook activity in manifest.

```
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

3) Also add metadata for your facebbok app id in manifest

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fbid"/>
```

you manifest should like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.solution.sa.myfb" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fbid"/>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

Still Have any issue , feel free to ask :-)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaDKP.png)

You can add your Facebook id in string class like that :

```
 <string name="fbid">your fb id</string>
```

image attached for you help

Comment: the meta-data is giving me an error. I asume I have to use the ID the fb provides, but I get an error about it not being able to resolve @string/id

Comment: Define your Facebook App Id in string class Like that :
<string name="fbid">1628325584101650</string>

Comment: Do I define this inside the activity or just before the meta line? And doesn't I have to type it like "android:name" and not just name? =)

Comment: `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` is deprecated